# How to use filter of SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have created Filter with this code:

```
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "SimplifiedLog";
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "RichTextFormate | *.rtf |Text Files | *.txt |All Files| *.*";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Simplified KL File";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

The problem is that every time I select any filter (Other than the selected one) it adds extension in the previous one. See Picture below:[image: Unwanted Filters]

Comment: I would remove the superfluous spaces.

Comment: how to remove superfluous spaces

Comment: I put it in a short answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should remove the spaces:

```
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "RichTextFormate|*.rtf|Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
```

The spaces after and before `|` are evaluated as is, so you should not add them if not necessary.

Comment: Ok so spaces causes all the problems Thanks for Help

Comment: I added spaces because it look clean and nicer without considering that it cause problem